# Unreachable Service - appsactivity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-activity

I have started receiving the message "Unreachable Service - appsactivity" today while executing my google apps script webapp. Anyone knows if there is an outage going on?

Answer (score 3):

> Unreachable Service - appsactivity

The previous answer is correct but the issue mentioned is now closed as a duplicate of

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647

Consider adding a star (on top left) to this issue instead. In addition, [a related error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169698149):

> Service not found: appsactivity v1

is also reported as duplicate of the above issue.

---

#### Possible solution(s):

- [Star the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647) to pressure Google into fixing it and wait.
- [#30](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647#comment30) - Remove `appsactivity` service from  manifest file: *appsscript.json*
- [#33](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647#comment33) - Disable V8 runtime
- [#43](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647#comment43) - Disable, save and re enable  Resources > Advanced Google services > Drive and Drive activity api
- [#49](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647#comment49) - Enable the [Apps activity api](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsactivity.googleapis.com/overview) "for the  project" you're having issue with.
- [#53](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169584647#comment53) - Delete current project and  create, use a new script

Comment: Thanks. #30 - Remove appsactivity service from manifest file: appsscript.json helped me

Answer (score 1):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169595450

Reported and assigned to someone at Google. Seems like an outage/unintended change.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be related to the deprecation of Drive Activity API v1. Google recommends migrating to v2 (See [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/upgrade-to-version-2-of-google-drive.html)).

You may need to clear caches, and perhaps even reactivate the advanced service.

Answer (score 1):

So I was also facing the same issue.
The issue tracker suggests that it is because of depreciation of Drive V1 Api although when I checked my drive API version it was already the latest one so I tried the following which worked.

Click on View>>show Manifest File to see a JSON file that contains scopes.

and remove Apps Activity scope (I have tested my app in dev mode all things are working I will go through the necessity of this scope later).
it should look like this

```
{
      "userSymbol": "AppsActivity",
      "serviceId": "appsactivity",
      "version": "v1"
    },
```

I hope this helps you please comment back your response.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: May 2nd 2021:**

After a lot of trial and error the solution above to disable the v8 runtime is partially correct and does function -- as long as you don't try to use any other scripts with the V8 runtime as a library.

The complete solution -- You can update individual scripts to V8 but if you have any libraries attached to the script that are not also upgraded to V8 then the script will throw the 'unable to locate appsactivity v1' error.

**Updating all of the scripts that are used as libraries to V8 as well was the key to fixing this issue** for my scripts.

Frustrating that Google is pushing the upgrade to v8 (disabling debugger, etc...) without first fixing this issue since this is going to really throw some folks (like myself for quite some time) for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it's Disable Runtime V8.

Open the script in the Apps Script editor. Select Run > Disable new Apps Script runtime powered by V8

Thats all

Im fixed my issue