# Google AppScript Wierd behaviour: Service not found: appsactivity v1

Tags: google-apps-script

I am facing some major issue with Google Appscript. My Script has two Libraries:

- A
- B

When I try to execute any script for example:

```
function funcfunc() {
  console.log("HEllo world");
}
```

excluding my library `A` it runs smoothly, but when I use `A` and `B` together, it throws an error. Both of these libraries are pretty big (in the sense have multiple files, jsons and classes). Further my earlier stable versions of `A` used to run with charm and when I restore to those versions, it will throw the same error which is described below (Even for the previous versions which have been used from months):

it gives me this error: `Service not found: appsactivity v1`. After hours of debugging I realized that something goes wrong during the initializations. After referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110083/unreachable-service-appsactivity), I suspect it to have something to do with `SpreadSheetApp` API, but as suggested in the solution, I can't replace all my
`ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` by `ss = SpreadsheeetApp.openById([sheet id])` as I need to perform the processing in new files whose Id I won't be knowing initially.

Is there any way to debug or know what's all happeining before `compilation` and during `initialization` in appscript? This issue seems to persist for more than two days now. If someone has any workaround or hack to solve this, do let me know.

Comment: If anyone wants to answer this question, add a answer in the linked duplicate question instead. That way, We have a single thread for all answers.

Comment: I won't say it as duplicate of the previous issue, as I had my question more about the way to debug initialization step and all the above was to get you familiar with my issue, to why do I need it or why am I looking for this answer.

Comment: If you feel it's not a duplicate, [edit] your  question to show why it's not a duplicate. If 3 other users agree, your question will be reopened. Given that the issue is due to Google messing with things not under your control and whatever answer posted in the linked question will be applicable here too, I'd leave this question as a duplicate. There's nothing more anyone can do or if there is, they can answer in the linked question instead.

Comment: Check my updated answer and see if any of it helps